# State is undefined after button click

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to play a bit with react native. I got an existing loging form and then I want to integrate it with a local API.

I'm doing a simple api call on button click, but my username/password state always comes in as undefined.

Can anyone help me figure out what's the issue?

Code bellow:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Alert, Button, Image, Pressable, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Switch, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import baseURL from './ApiUtils';

const logo = require("./assets/icon.png")

export default function LoginForm() {
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
const { username, setUsername } = useState("");
const { password, setPassword } = useState("");
const Login = data => {
    console.log(username); // comming in as undefined
    console.log(password); // comming in as undefined
    return baseURL
        .post('login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(
            response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            },
            error => {
                console.log('postAnswer error: ' + error);
            },
        );
};

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

        <Image source={logo} style={styles.image} resizeMode='contain' />
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='EMAIL OR USERNAME' value={username} onChangeText={setUsername} autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize='none' />
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='PASSWORD' secureTextEntry value={password} onChangeText={setPassword} autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize='none' />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rememberView}>
            <View style={styles.switch}>
                <Switch value={click} onValueChange={setClick} trackColor={{ true: "green", false: "gray" }} />
                <Text style={styles.rememberText}>Remember Me</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Pressable onPress={Login}>
                <Text >LOGIN</Text>
            </Pressable>

        </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

Comment: useState returns an array not an object. Do this: const [username, setUsername  = useState("")